# Joomla 4 Reinstall Core FIles

Tags: joomla-4

Joomla 4.2.8 (current stable at time of writing)

What does the button **Reinstall Joomla! Core Files** actually do? What are the 'core files'?

I am experiencing some issues on my site and I've seen this as a suggested resolution.

I'm not sure if doing this will have any other adverse affect on my site?

My site is pretty standard, no overrides or customisations (apart from css). I have several third party plugins and extensions installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **installs all the files** from Joomla 4.2.8 that are **in Joomla! 4.2.8 Full Package** (.zip) https://downloads.joomla.org/cms/joomla4/4-2-8 **except** from the **/installation folder**.

It does not touch your configuration.php and neither the extensions that you installed yourself.

If did your changes the right way, using template overrides, then those won't be overwritten either.

In any case, before such large changes as these, it's recommended to create a full back-up of your website (files + database), e.g. using Akeeba Backup.